# How to query nested data in mongoose model

Tags: mongodb, express, vue.js, mongoose, vuex

I am attempting to build a Vue.js app with a MEVN stack backend and Vuex. I am configuring my Vuex action handler with a GET request that prompts a corresponding Express GET route to query data nested in Mongoose.

A username is passed into the handler as an argument and appended to the GET request URL as a parameter:

```
  actions: {
    loadPosts: async (context, username) => {
      console.log(username)
      let uri = `http://localhost:4000/posts/currentuser?username=${username}`;
      const response = await axios.get(uri)
      context.commit('setPosts', response.data)
    }
  }
```

The corresponding Express route queries `activeUser.name`, which represents the nested data in the Mongoose Model:

```
postRoutes.route('/currentuser').get(function (req, res) {
  let params = {},
    username = req.query.activeUser.name
    if (username) {
       params.username = username
    }
    Post.find(params, function(err, posts){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
});
```

Below is my Mongoose model, with `activeUser.name` representing the nested data queried by the Express route:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Post = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
  },
  activeUser: {
    name: {
      type: String
    }
  }
},{
    collection: 'posts'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', Post);
```

Even with this setup, the GET route does not appear to send a response back to the action handler. I thought adding `username = req.query.activeUser.name` in the express route would be the right method for querying the nested data in Mongoose, but apparently not. Any recommendations on how to configure the above Express route in order to query the nested data in the Mongoose model? Thanks!

Comment: what is the output `posts`

Comment: Manjeet Thakur, could you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: Post.find(params, function(err, posts){  console.log(err, posts)}

Comment: I tried console.log there, but got no output. The server is returning an error: ```Cannot read property 'name' of undefined```

Comment: change req.query.activeUser.name to req.query.activeUser.username

Comment: Tried it just now, but doesn't work. Shouldn't it be some variation of: ```  activeUser: { name: { type: String }}``` similar to what's in the Mongoose model?

Comment: check  uri carefully `let uri = `http://localhost:4000/posts/currentuser?username=${username};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is inside `activeuser` so you need to construct params object variable like this:

```js
postRoutes.route("/currentuser").get(function(req, res) {
  let params = {
    activeUser: {}
  };

  let username = req.query.activeUserName;

  if (username) {
    params.activeUser.name = username;
  }

  Post.find(params, function(err, posts) {
    if (err) {
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(posts);
    }
  });
});
```

Note that I also used activeUserName as query param like this: `/currentuser?activeUserName=JS_is_awesome18`

Comment: Your answer also greatly improved my understanding of how querying in an Express route works. Much appreciated.